# Windows explorer.exe cannot open any folder, while right click open works fine

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

When double clicking any folder, or trying to directly start 'explorer.exe' in any way either the following message pops up:

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file...

or nothing happens at all.

However **right-click open a folder works fine**. Despite the default target is also set to open. I cannot figure out which permissions could be missing.

Comment: Questions: (1) What do you mean by "directly start explorer.exe"? (2) Which account are you using? (3) Does it happen on absolutely all folders? (4) Does it happen when booting in [Safe mode](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-start-windows-7-in-safe-mode-2624540)? (5) Run [sfc /scannow](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html) to check for Windows errors.

Comment: 1) Clicking explorer.exe or run it through cmd.exe, or pressing Win-E, or clicking on any folder including special folders like system preferences. Run as Administrator, run as other user all fail. 2) No admin user account, I also tried switching him to admin w/o success.3) I couldn't find any exception yet. 4) Also happens in safe mode, 5) Sfc didn't find any issue.

Comment: Try also to disable the antivirus (if it runs in Safe mode). If you cannot find any hint to the problem, this only leaves [Repair Install](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).